# Find posts without accepted answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The unanswered tab works well on most other SE sites since having an answer is more indicative of the question being solved (not guaranteed though). On this site since you are allowed to make a well thought out guess as an answer, it is very likely answered posts haven't actually been solved unless an answer has been accepted.

While I like looking at all posts and seeing if I can answer them, I find it more exciting to try and solve a puzzle that hasn't already been solved by someone else.

My question is whether it is currently possible to filters posts in such a way to only show me questions that don't have accepted answers, or if you think that having such a feature would be a good thing to add.

Comment: I like this idea - I've wanted it myself. **Possible pitfall:** a lot of the posts with no accepted answer were made by people who have since left the site; the feature would still be useful, but your attempts at answering may not prove fruitful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can enter "hasaccepted:no" in the search box to search for questions without an accepted answer.

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for and even doesn't require tags to be specified. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer. ;)